# Descriptive name for EKSource in iOS5

Tags: ios, ios5, eventkit

I've been trying to get a descriptive title for an `EKSource` on iOS5 for a while now, but the problem I keep running into is that the title of an external exchange source is always "Exchange", even though the native calendar app presents the source as "aname@gmail.com"

`src` is an `EKSource*`

```
 NSString *sourceTitle = [src title];
```

returns only "Exchange".

```
 NSString *sourceTitle = [src description];
```

returns the debugging print info, as expected.

However, in the native calendar app (and in another 3rd party app) this same source is presented as "aname@gmail.com". How do I dig that name out from `src`?

Comment: Did you spell `EKEventStore` wrong? A google search for EKEventSource shows exactly one hit.

Comment: D'oh! Not a spelling error, exactly, but wrong nonetheless...